# SpaCy Matcher did not return a match

Tags: python, nlp, matcher

I have the following codes:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)

patterns = [{"LOWER": "self"}, {"LOWER": "employed"}, {"OP": "?"},  {"OP": "?"}, {"OP": "?"}, {"LOWER": "average"}]
    
matcher.add("Category 1", None, patterns)
    
doc = nlp(u"I am a self employed working in a remote factory. I have a flat located in NYC, but I want to sell it to change for a new one. This new flat is situated in Connecticut, facing a nice lake.  This flat could be sold for 0.5 million dollars. That is an average price in the neighborhood")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
        rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'CategoryID'
        span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
        print(rule_id, span.text)
```

It does not return any match. What I expect to see is

```
# Category 1 self employed average
```

I create this fake sentence to extract 'self employed' and 'average'. In reality,
we do not know how the sentence looks like.

My purpose is to extract 'self employed' and 'average', no matter where they are and what terms' sequence is (for example, average is before self employed).

How to approach it? Thank you for any feedback

Comment: Matcher does sequence matching only on tokens. 
Problem here is with `"self employed"` as a token.
Your Category1 matcher is looking or tokens that match value of "self employed" and since "self" and "employed" are two different tokens (in your actual doc) it is failing to find a match

Comment: Yes, I separate the term, it works. I modified the question again. I appreciate any ideas.